# Render partial view with updated value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc project using views and partial views.
Multiple partial views are being rendered in single view. Now my problem is that when ever i update some values in partial view and render it again through controller it does not show partial view with updated value.... to see updated value i have to refresh the page each time.

Comment: By "i update some values" do you mean you send an ajax request?

Comment: Please give more details on how are you updating those views and preferably provide sample code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried placing your partial views in a form and posting the form when you change the values?

Comment: well if you place a form around your partial views and either submit the form from an ajax request or from a submit button click. depends on how your updating your partial view - i'd have to see your code.